# Running function on exit of C# program not working properly

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a working C#/xaml program for Windows. I need to run a function when the user closes the program using the "x" in the upper-right-hand-corner of the screen. I have tried pretty much everything but can't seem to figure out why it is not working. Below is some of the code I have that is not working so far:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window {

    bool shutdown = false;

    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();
        OutputManagerThread.Start();
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += new EventHandler(OnExit);
    }

    void OnExit(object sender,EventArgs e) {
        shutdown = true;
    }
}
```

Why doesn't this OnExit function ever do anything. I can't print from it or execute any other code inside that function.

Thanks

Comment: Is this a WPF application ?

Comment: When the *process* exits the form is already closed and disposed.

Comment: yes this is a wpf application

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't the right event. You want [Window.Closing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.closing(v=vs.85).aspx).

> The Closing event is raised when Close is called, if a window's Close
>   button is clicked, or if the user presses ALT+F4.